# Changing keyboard language problem in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, keyboard, shortcuts

I want to change the shortcut of changing language of the keyboard , but when I set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as shortcut, it set as "Disabled".

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System Setting** → **Keyboard Layout** → **Options** → **Key(s) to change layout** and tick **Alt+Shift**:

[image: Keyboard Layout Options]